# Queueing event for a minute

Tags: php, laravel-5

Currently im trying to run a Event on the background and queue this. After it has ran, i want to broadcast the output.

In my app/Events/ folder i have a class (listener) EventsSynchronised what looks like this:

```
class EventsSynchronised extends Event implements ShouldBroadcast, ShouldQueue
    {
        use SerializesModels;
        use InteractsWithQueue;

        public function __construct( )
        {
            Log::info('ES constructor');
        }

        /**
         * Get the channels the event should be broadcast on.
         *
         * @return array
         */
        public function broadcastOn()
        {
            return [ 'test-channel' ];
        }
    }
```

I have a handler for whats need to be done after the listener is called:

```
class HandleInput
    {
        public function __construct()
        {

        }

        public function handle( EventsSynchronised $event )
        {

            Log::info('HI handle()');

        }

    }
```

So now i need to register those to the EventServiceProvider

```
class EventServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
    {
        /**
         * The event listener mappings for the application.
         *
         * @var array
         */
        protected $listen = [
            EventsSynchronised::class => [
                HandleInput::class
            ],
        ];

        /**
         * Register any other events for your application.
         *
         * @param  \Illuminate\Contracts\Events\Dispatcher $events
         * @return void
         */
        public function boot( DispatcherContract $events )
        {
            parent::boot( $events );

            //
        }
    }
```

After preparing everything, i add a route to test:

```
Route::get( 'send', function ()
    {
        Event::fire( new EventsSynchronised() );
    } );
```

What happens is that the HandleInput::class is called immediately without being queued, how can i solve this? I also tried $this->release(60) to hold it for a minute.